# If in an inner product space $\langle x,u\rangle=\langle x,v\rangle$ for all $x$, show that $u=v$.

Tags: linear-algebra

If in an inner product space $\langle x,u\rangle=\langle x,v\rangle$ for all $x$, show that $u=v$.

This seems obvious to me, so how do I prove it? Proof by contradiction maybe?

Any suggestions would be nice.

Comment: Please don't use $<$ and $>$ for inner products. Those are *relation symbols*, and they not only look wrong, they also get the spacing associated with relations. Use `\langle` and `\rangle` to get $\langle$ and $\rangle$.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let $x=u-v$, then:

$$\langle x,u\rangle-\langle x,v\rangle=\langle x,u-v\rangle=\langle u-v,u-v\rangle=0$$

So $u-v=0$.

Comment: See my comment on the question, above.